# Passing an intent value from notification to an activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

```
    /** Updates the notification. */
void updateNotification(String text) {
    Log.i(TAG, text);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "nikhil", text, pi);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

/**
 * Configures service as a foreground service. A foreground service is a service that's doing
 * something the user is actively aware of (such as playing music), and must appear to the
 * user as a notification. That's why we create the notification here.
 */
void setUpAsForeground(String text) {

/*  Intent launchIntent;
    String myType="one";

    launchIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    launchIntent.putExtra("checkme", myType);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), -1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
*/  
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class),


            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    notification = new Notification();
    notification.tickerText = text;
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_playing;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "nikhil", text, pi);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Above codes are from my service class , all i need to pass a string with the intent to MainActivity class . i tried a lot from Stackover flow but nothing works . please help .

Comment: use extras to pass some dara to the Intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
void updateNotification(String text) {
Log.i(TAG, text);


Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class):
n.putExtra("key", yourValue);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        n),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "nikhil", text, pi);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: ur wel come. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
String myType="one";
Intent gotoIntent = new Intent();
gotoIntent.setClassName(mContext,"YOURPACKAGENAME.MainActivity");
gotoIntent.putExtra("checkme", myType);

contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,(int) (Math.random() * 100), gotoIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notification = new Notification();
notification.tickerText = text;
notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_playing;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "nikhil", text, contentIntent);
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: yes which easy way to solve your problem and i try another way np thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateNotification(String msg) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to update notification...: " + msg);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).putExtra("keyName", ValueOfKey), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification update successfully.");
}
```

Comment: ok .. please my answer is right then give me upVote and make answer is right please

Comment: your answer cannot be right since contentIntent.putExtra(...), PendingIntent doesn't have such a method

Comment: @ Nikhil yes sorry i pass intent directly in pendingIntent ..now i modified it